# How do I compute the coordinates of the points of tangency of a circle inscribed in a triangle?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, geometry

I am trying to demonstrate properties of the Gergonne point of a triangle. I can draw the triangle and its in-circle, but I'm having trouble finding the points of tangency for the in-circle. These and the triangle's vertices locate the Gergonne point.

This is my code:

```
InCircle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}] := With[{
u = Norm[{x2, y2} - {x3, y3}],
v = Norm[{x3, y3} - {x1, y1}],
w = Norm[{x1, y1} - {x2, y2}]}, 
Circle[(u {x1, y1} + v {x2, y2} + w {x3, y3})/(u + v + w), 
1/2 Sqrt[-(((u - v - w) (u + v - w) (u - v + w)))/(u + v + w)]]];
Manipulate[
Graphics[{Thick, Green, Line[{a[[1]], a[[2]], a[[3]], a[[1]]}], Red, 
Thick, InCircle[a[[1]], a[[2]], a[[3]]]}, 
PlotRange -> 6.0], {{a, {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {0, 1}}}, Locator}]
```

I've tried to use "inter" but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "inter"?

Comment: Your question has been answered, and there are [things to do after that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Its good practice to wait 24 hours for other answers before up-voting and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. I think now is time to either clarify or accept the best answer. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 6):

A function for the triangle incircle.

```
Incircle[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}}] := 
   With[{a = Sqrt[Apply[Plus, {x2 - x3, y2 - y3}^2]], 
         b = Sqrt[Apply[Plus, {x3 - x1, y3 - y1}^2]], 
         c = Sqrt[Apply[Plus, {x1 - x2, y1 - y2}^2]]}, 
        Circle[(a {x1, y1} + b {x2, y2} + c {x3, y3})/(a + b + c), 
           1/2 Sqrt[-(((a - b - c) (a + b - c) (a - b + c))/(a + b + c))]]]
```

The incircle contact points can be found as follows.

```
IncircleContacts[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}}] :=
   With[{a = Norm[{x2, y2} - {x3, y3}],
         b = Norm[{x1, y1} - {x3, y3}], 
         c = Norm[{x1, y1} - {x2, y2}]}, 
      {{(a (x1 - x2) + b (-x1 + x2) + c (x1 + x2))/(2 c),
        (a (y1 - y2) + b (-y1 + y2) + c (y1 + y2))/(2 c)}, 
       {((b - c) (x2 - x3) + a (x2 + x3))/(2 a),
        ((b - c) (y2 - y3) + a (y2 + y3))/(2 a)},
       {(a (x1 - x3) + c (-x1 + x3) + b (x1 + x3))/(2 b),
        (a (y1 - y3) + c (-y1 + y3) + b (y1 + y3))/(2 b)}}]
```

A function for the intersection point of two lines.

```
IntersectLines[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, {{u1_, v1_}, {u2_, v2_}}] :=
   Module[{det = (-y1 + y2) (u1 - u2) - (x1 - x2) (-v1 + v2)},
      If[N[det] =!= 0.,
        (1/det)*
           {-(x2 y1 - x1 y2) (u1 - u2) + (x1 - x2) (u2 v1 - u1 v2),
            (x2 y1 - x1 y2) (-v1 + v2) - (-y1 + y2) (u2 v1 - u1 v2)},
        {}]]
```

You can visualise the Gergonne point as follows.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{a = Norm[v3 - v2], b = Norm[v3 - v1], c = Norm[v2 - v1], w, g},
      w = IncircleContacts[{v1, v2, v3}];
      g = IntersectLines[{v1, w[[2]]}, {v2, w[[3]]}];
      Graphics[{
         Thick, PointSize[0.02],
         Line[{v1, v2, v3, v1}],
         Red, Incircle[{v1, v2, v3}],
         Blue, Point[w],
         Blue, Line[{v1, w[[2]]}], Line[{v2, w[[3]]}], Line[{v3, w[[1]]}]
   }, PlotLabel -> {v1, v2, v3, g}]],
 {{v1, {0, 0}}, Locator},
 {{v2, {1, 0}}, Locator},
 {{v3, {0.3, 0.7}}, Locator}
]
```

[image: Gergonne point]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) functionality::

```
GergonneGraphic[pts_]:=Module[{s=Insphere[SetPrecision[pts,16]], tangents, lines},
    tangents = Table[
        RegionIntersection[s, Line @ Delete[pts, i]],
        {i, 3}
    ];
    lines = MapThread[Line[{#[[1,1]], #2}]&, {tangents, pts}];
    gergonne = RegionIntersection @@ lines;
    Graphics[
        {
        Green, RegionBoundary @ Triangle[pts],
        Red, s,
        LightBlue, lines,
        Blue, tangents,
        Orange, PointSize[Large], gergonne
        },
        PlotRange->6
    ]
]

Manipulate[GergonneGraphic[a], {{a, {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {0, 1}}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Note that I used [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision) to avoid issues with numeric fuzz that can cause the intersection of the incircle and the tangent line to be an empty region.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {5, 3, 2}];
npts = Table[RegionNearest[Line@#, First[Insphere@p]] & /@ Subsets[p, {2}], {p, pts}];
Row[Table[Graphics[{Yellow, Polygon @ pts[[i]], Red, Insphere @ pts[[i]], 
 Blue, PointSize[Scaled[.05]], Point /@ npts[[i]]}, ImageSize -> 150], {i, 5}]]
```

[image]